# strcmp: fields within lines

Tags: c, pointers, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm writing a version of strcmp that has the option of comparing strings only on the basis of space and alphanumeric characters (directory order) as well as the option of being blind to case distinctions (Kernighan and Ritchie page 121 5-16). So I came up with the following:

```
int strcmpdf (char* s, char* t)
{
    char a[100];
    char b[100];
    int i;
    int j;
    i = j = 0;
    if (directory){ /*compares strings solely on the basis of alphanumeric/space characters*/
        for (   ; *s != '\0'; s++)
            if (isalnum(*s) || isspace (*s) || *s == '\t' || *s == '\n')
                a[i++] = (fold && islower(*s))? toupper(*s) : *s;
        a[i] = '\0';
        for (   ; *t != '\0'; t++)
            if (isalnum(*t) || isspace (*t) || *t == '\t' || *t == '\n')
                b[j++] = (fold && islower(*t))? toupper(*t) : *t;
        b[j] = '\0';
        return strcmp(a,b);
    }else if (fold && !directory){/*folds upper and lower cases together*/
        for (   ; toupper(*s) == toupper(*t); s++,t++)
            if (*s == '\0')
                return 0;
        return toupper(*s) - toupper(*t);
    }else
        return strcmp(s,t);
}
```

This works fine and answers the question but problems start when I start using char pointers instead of arrays. When, instead of arrays a and b, I initialize char* a and char* b, and replace the a[i++] with *a++ on line 11 and 12 and b[j++] with *b++ on line 15 and 16, I get a segmentation fault. Why do I get this error when a+i is the address of a[i]?

Comment: What are char* a and char* b initialized to?

Comment: I'd double check the if statements - perhaps add a print to each condition to see when it gets to each point.

Comment: Sorry, I meant declare. when I declare char * a and char * b.

Comment: did you do 'char *a = malloc(100);'?

Comment: no I didn't allocate memory. I just initialized char* a and char *b.

Comment: Here's the entire code. I replaced a[100] with char* a and b[100] with char* b. On linux mint I get a segmentation fault when I use the -d flag. On windows the program just stops working. http://pastebin.com/Bc0eHYLk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an array such as 'char a[100]', it allocates 100 chars (bytes) on the stack, and 'a' points to the first char.

When you declare a pointer such as 'char *a', it doesn't point to anything valid initially.  You cannot assign anything to '*a' until it references something valid.

What you could do is something like:

```
char aa[100];
char *a = aa;

*a = '\0';
```

(I made a similar mistake myself when I was started learning C, and got seg faults too).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was having a look at this : http://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Tips/tips_on_segmentation.html

Its the fourth common cause : Failure to initialize a pointer before using it, right?

Comment: There is a tool called 'valgrind' that is great at finding "stray pointers" and other bugs.  It's available in most linux/unix distros.

Comment: Thank you; I'm downloading it.